# output.write(bytearray(image[y][x])) TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytearray

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to generate Mandelbrot set and dump image in the directory .py file is saved

```
import math
width = 640
height = 480
image = [[[255 for c in range(3)] for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
for y in range(height):
    imag = (y-(height/2)) / float(height)*2.5
    for x in range(width):
        real = ((x-(width/2)) / float(width)*2.5)-0.5
        z = complex ( real, imag )
        c = z
        for i in range(255):
            z = z*z + c
            if ( abs(z)>2.5 ):
                image[y][x]=[i,i,i]
                break

output = open ( 'mandelbrot_set.ppm', 'w' )
output.write("P6 " + str(width) + " " + str(height) + " 255\n")
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        output.write(bytearray(image[y][x]))
output.close()
```

Expected output is image of mandelbrot set in directory, where I do get a file but it shows nothing and there is error in terminal, which is as following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mandelbrot.py", line 21, in <module>
    output.write(bytearray(image[y][x]))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytearray
```

Comment: To be clear: `write` expects a string, and you *explicitly* converted the data you want written to a `bytearray`?

Comment: Honestly I don't know the details of the program, it is copied from the "Quora"
LInk is here, I hope its okay to provide
https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-graph-the-Mandelbrot-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write binary data to the file you have to open it in **binary mode**:

```
output = open ( 'mandelbrot_set.ppm', 'wb' )
```

But, in that case, you wont be able to write text, so the line:

```
output.write("P6 " + str(width) + " " + str(height) + " 255\n")
```

will throw an error. You should encode such string:

```
output.write(("P6 " + str(width) + " " + str(height) + " 255\n").encode())
```

That will convert the string to an array of bytes (a `bytes` object) using the specified encoding, which is `utf-8` by-default.

Comment: You might improve this by pointing out how `bytes` literals work, so they can make that text output line output bytes...

Comment: Thank you! 
Replacing
output = open ( 'mandelbrot_set.ppm', 'w' )
By
output = open ( 'mandelbrot_set.ppm', 'wb' )

And including 
output.write(("P6 " + str(width) + " " + str(height) + " 255\n").encode())

Solved the issue. And I'm very sorry that I don't know the details of programming, so may have done some basic mistaked ^.^'